# Azure IIS webconfig rewrite url php

Tags: php, web-config, url-rewriting

I have problem with web.config rewrite rules for php. This is my rules

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>

        <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
          <match url="^index" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Rewrite to blog.php">
          <match url="^blog" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="blog.php" />
        </rule>

         <rule name="Rewrite to certain blog.php">
          <match url="^blog/([0-9]+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="blog.php?id={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And when i go to blog/16 for example, opens blog.php without any css. Where is problem?

Comment: I find problem.

In url there is problem with &, so I change it with &amp; and all works fine.